# How is a for loop possible while using a Map?

Tags: loops, for-loop, kotlin, iterator

AFAIK a **Map** doesn't declare that it implements *Iterable* (in contrast to *Collection* which does).
So how is it possible to run over all map entries using a for loop?
Code:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String,Int>("One" to 1, "Two" to 2, "Three" to 3, "Four" to 4)
for (element in map)
{
        println(element.value)
}
```

Comment: You can get a list of the Keys and iterate over them or simply get a list of all the values and iterate thru them (depending on what you need to do)

Comment: @blurfus, but i'm not  talking on running over keys or values. My question is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing `Iterable` isn't the requirement to be *iterable* but instead https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops states

> `for` iterates through anything that provides an iterator, i.e.
> has a member- or extension-function `iterator()`, whose return type
> has a member- or extension-function `next()`, and
> has a member- or extension-function `hasNext()` that returns `Boolean`.
> All of these three functions need to be marked as `operator`.

and https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/ actually has a `iterator()` that fits those requirements

> Returns an `Iterator` over the entries in the `Map`.

Comment: thanks. i really didn't notice it. But shouldn't it declare that it implements an Iterable (Collection does declare), in order that the for will work?

Comment: @Eitanos30 it is just that there is this interface `Iterable` that conveniently provides this required function but anyone can provide this function and become *iterable* without using that interface.

Comment: I see. So can you tell me what is the advantage (is there?) for declaring that a class implements an Iterable? only for polymorphism purpose?

Comment: I'd say that is exactly the reason, yes.